# Lync SBC Issues

Tags: lync, lync-2013

Ok, I have been working with Lync 2013 for 2 years now. I got to this job and watched a consultant install Lync 2013 and walk away. I have been reading some books and have some questions about how things are setup. I am curious and need to know if things should change or why they are setup the way they are.

I have 2 Sangoma Boxes. This means I have 2 Front End servers with the Edge and Reverse Proxy as VMs on the same box. There is only 16 GB of RAM so they are very overloaded. We only have about 100 Phone users so maybe this setup makes sense.

This is my question the SBC Level 3 provided is not "Lync Compliant" so do I change to RTP with QoS and hope call quality gets better or power up the software version (VM on one of the overloaded Front End Servers) and use it so I can use RTCP?

Comment: 100 Phone users didn´t seamed to be that much assuming each box has 16 GB ram and not the whole hardware guest OS where all machines are running on. Did you deployed the [Statistic Manager](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/323-deploy-the-statistics-manager-for-skype-for-business-server.html) or the [Call Quality dashboard](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/skypeforbusiness/300-install-the-skype-for-business-call-quality-dashboard.html) so your could check that in more details? By the way are your sure you have 2 fronted server and not 3?

Comment: I did not know about these this is awesome. Can I install the Quality dashboard on the SQL monitoring server with no conflicts? Yes, I have 2 Front End Servers, 2 Edge Servers, 2 Reverse Proxies, I can have 2 SBC servers but those are powered down at the moment.

Comment: that depends on your environment and isn´t that easy to say as i do not know your environment. But I think both might help to find any performance issues.